# How to add Row Above in GridPane(Javafx) automatically by clicking "add" button

Tags: javafx

I would like to add a Row above in GridPane which index 0, the problem is when I add an element in GridPane `MyGrid.add(Label, 0, 0)` this label will overlap with the previous Label in emplacement (0, 0)

my Grid in FXML

```xml
<GridPane fx:id="CalenderGrid" hgap="5.0" layoutX="464.0" layoutY="225.0" prefHeight="191.0" prefWidth="271.0" vgap="5.0">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label text="Effectif" />
            <Label text="Femme" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Admins et managements" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label text="Ingénieurs et techniciens" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label text="Ouvriers et saisonniers" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <TextField fx:id="NbrFemmes" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" promptText="nbr de Personnes" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <TextField fx:id="NbrAdmManag" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" promptText="nbr de Personnes" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextField fx:id="NbrIngTech" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" promptText="nbr de Personnes" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <TextField fx:id="NbrOuvrSais" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" promptText="nbr de Personnes" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <TextField fx:id="Effectif" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="100.0" promptText="ZIM" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </padding>
      </GridPane>
```

code in controller

```
private Label AnneeInfo = new Label("année");
private TextField AnneeEffectif = new TextField();



//Action in button
AnneeEffectif.setLayoutX(60);
CalenderGrid.add(AnneeInfo, 0, 0);
CalenderGrid.add(AnneeEffectif, 1, 0);
```

Comment: If you are facing this kind of situation (the need to prepend rows in a GridPane when you are adding data), then maybe using a TableView could be more relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to increment the row index of every child previously in the `GridPane`, i.e. something like this:

```
//Action in button
AnneeEffectif.setLayoutX(60);

// add constraint for new row
List<RowConstraints> constraints = CalenderGrid.getRowConstraints();
constraints.add(constraints.get(0));

// move all children down one row
insertRows(1);

CalenderGrid.addRow(0, AnneeInfo, AnneeEffectif);
```

```
private void insertRows(int count) {
    for (Node child : CalenderGrid.getChildren()) {
        Integer rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(child);
        GridPane.setRowIndex(child, rowIndex == null ? count : count + rowIndex);
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you want to add the row multiple times storing the new `Node`s in fields and not creating them in the action handler of the button seems wrong, since you can't use the `Node`s in the scene more than once.