# JavaFX: Adding a row into a GridPane

Tags: java, javafx

Given a `GridPane` loaded from an FXML. The `GirdPane`contains the row 0, 1, 2 and the colums 0, and 1.

I now want to add a new row after row 1. If I use `GridPane#addRow(Int, Node*)` the two nodes won't be add as a new row but added as additional nodes to the existing row 2.

How can I add a new row between row 1 and 2?

Comment: You'll have to set the constraints of the nodes in row two to be in row three if you want to "insert" a row.

Comment: @Slaw Could you point me to an example to do that?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649819/how-to-add-row-above-in-gridpanejavafx-automatically-by-clicking-add-button